# UiTextField with horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

i have a simple question, but i still not able to figure a answer.

There is any option to enable/add a horizontal scroll gesture in a UITextField, so the user could scroll the text to see the hidden text? The textfield should be editable too.

Thanks

Comment: my question was about a UITextField not a UITextView

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to programmatically scroll a `UITextField` as would be necessary in doing what you've described...

Instead I recommend creating a `UITextField` as a subview of a `UIScrollView`, where the `UITextField` expands to contain the text as it's typed; so perhaps you can (1) scroll using the `UIScrollView` itself or (2) attach a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `UITextField` then have the UIScrollView change its content offset in response to a horizontal swipe.

Comment: I can have the textView inside the scrollView, the problem is how to present the text when the text it´s typed. How to make the contentOffset to work properly. Any idea?